# check if file has been changed with js

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, iframe, src

i have some code that has two iframes but connected to the same file but one has a auto refresher to get the newest change and i want my 'if' statement to execute when they are not the same but its not working, the if statement is not executing although one has more text than the other (changed) my code below, its simple.

```
 var iframeContent = getElementById('frame1');
    
setTimeout(function () {

    var iframeContent1 = getElementById("frame");


  
        if(iframeContent1 !== iframeContent) {
        
      
        window.location.href= './';
        }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setInterval` function instead of `setTimeout` function to check file content every 3 second like below given example.

```
var iframeContent = getElementById('frame1');

setInterval(function () {

    var iframeContent1 = getElementById("frame");

    if (iframeContent1 !== iframeContent) {

        window.location.href= './';

    }

}, 3000);
```

Comment: ok tysm! ill change it now

Comment: @kingcannibal Sir, Is your Problem Solved or Not ?

Comment: Sir, If your Problem Solved then accept my answer on Stack overflow by click on tick icon left side of my answer.